# Is there a point of beating Vault of Glass raid on Hard after finishing on Normal?

Tags: destiny

I beat the vault of glass on normal mode, but I got no items just ascendent energy/shards. 
Now I'm wondering if I were to beat it on hard, would I get anything else? I know the chests that I've opened in normal model won't give me anything, but what about the rest of the raid?

I also noticed that after I beat  Vault of Glass on normal, it still says there are rewards, does that mean I can do it as many times as I'd like per week and still have a chance of getting raid gear?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you go on bungie.net, log in, and go to your character then click advisors, you'll see your raid progression as a bar fragmented into 8 sections:  4 for normal, 4 for hard.  These represent the 4 drop points in the raid:

- Oracles
- Templar
- Gatekeeper
- Aetheon

Completing the raid on hard mode first will give you double drop rolls, as you'll get a chance for drops from normal mode at the same time.  You also get double drops from the left chest in the Gorgon maze, the only chest that drops in both difficulties.  Basically, if you can complete hard mode, you don't even have to bother doing normal anymore and you get the same amount of loot as if you completed both.

It's also good to know, that the double rolls you get in hard mode will BOTH roll on hard mode gear, thus giving you a doubled chance to get the hard mode only weapons and helmets.

In addition, the loot table includes more things in hard mode that don't drop in normal mode, off the top of my head:

- Fatebringer (legendary, arc, hand cannon)
- Praedyths Timepiece (legendary, arc, pulse rifle)
- Praetorian Foil (legendary, solar, fusion rifle)
- Vex Mythoclast (exotic, primary, solar, fusion rifle, drops from Aetheon only)
- Raid helmets for all 3 classes (the legendary ones that max out at 30 light and drop from Aetheon only)
- Aspect of Glass (a ship)

Comment: @downvoter any criticism? My answer is correct and complete as far as I'm aware

Comment: @user4084312 please do not edit answers and write that this is a copy of someone else's answer.  1) It isn't a copy, although it contains similar information required to answer the question and 2) that's not what edits are for

Comment: so if I were to do hard mode first, would I get the same amount of items I would if I were to do normal first, then hard? Last time I got 2 items in normal, then 2 items in hard.

Comment: @echad correct, you would not get any items from normal if you did hard mode first, you'd get double items from hard

Comment: It is also to note that the common assumption is that running the raid on hard before running on normal will give you 2x the drops. The benefit is that both drops will be on the Hard Raid loot table allowing you to get 2 chances at the hard mode loot mentioned above. [source](http://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/2ks420/sga_if_you_can_do_hard_mode_vog_first_and_skip/)

Comment: @Mondrianaire good point, I didn't even think of that, but it's definitely true.  Will update

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a point.

If you do normal VoG then hard mode VoG you will get a set from the loot table of both normal and hard-mode.

Also keep in mind you will get double of the hard-mode loot if you don't do VoG on normal mode and just skip to hard mode.

So to sum it up, if you have a group that can do hard-mode VoG then don't even bother with the normal version. Waste of time, as you have to do two raids instead of one, and you get less hard-mode loot.

Comment: If that's the case, I'd say "more loot" because last night all i got were ascendent energy and few shards but no items so double that would be nothing =/.

Comment: ... Strange Coins? wat?

Comment: Strange Coins don't drop from the hard mode raid.. it's not at all relevant

Comment: @turbo Read this: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/704532-destiny/70326282

Comment: Right, he's comparing the weekly heroic on the lowest level vs. the highest level to the raid on normal vs. hard. No offense, but have you played the game? I've been clearing the raid on hard mode 3x a week since the second week of the raid and I've **never** gotten strange coins.

Comment: @turbo  edited, and just saying no offense isn't going to make it not offensive. I have not played in hardmode VoG though, I admit :p

Comment: I know, I legitimately did not mean to offend you though, I was curious.  I have seen people just googling around and compiling answers for games they've never played and I wasn't sure what the deal was here.

Comment: @turbo I'm just joking, no offense taken.